# How to use variables in _hyperscript js

Tags: hyperscript

I'm having fun with [_hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/) js which I find very promising and amusing.

Now I'm trying to understand the use of variables inside simple commands. Suppose that I have the following code generated by a PHP script that queried a dB and where ids are obtained the dB (a very common case):

```
<div id="1000">Mercedes</div>
<div id="1022">Audi</div>
<div id="1301">Ferrari</div>
<div id="1106">Lamborghini</div>
```

To add a class to a specific `id` I would normally do like this:

```
<button _="on click add .green to #1022" type="button">
    Click
</button>
```

But what if I don't know the `id` because it's the result of a dB query? How can I place a variable using [_hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org) and set it with javascript? Something like this:

```
<button _="on click call setID() then add .green to ???" type="button">
    Click
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setID() {
        // here the code to get the ID 
        return id;
    }
</script>
```

Using the '[symbol](https://hyperscript.org/docs/#zoo)' `it` to read the result of the last `call` returns error:

```
_="on click call setID() then add .green to it"
```

returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: target.classList is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string templates inside query literals, so something like this should work:

```html
<button _="on click add .green to <#${getIdToAddTo()}/>" type="button">
    Click
</button>
```

where the `<.../>` is the query literal and the `${getIdToAddTo()}` is a string template within that query

Another alternative would be to create a method that returns the div to add to:

```html
<script>
  function divToAddTo() {
    return document.getElementById("whatever");
  }
</script>
<button _="on click add .green to divToAddTo()" type="button">
    Click
</button>
```

Comment: Hi 1cg! Why I can't do (or why hyperscript does'nt offer) something like this: _="on click call setID() then add .green to it" where I simply use the result ('it') of the call? Woud'nt be more natural and easier?

Comment: First solution <#${getIdToAddTo()}/> worked fine. Second solution reported A target expression must be writable : functionCall undefined

Comment: The `setID()` returns a string?  In this case you still need to use a query literal to get at it, to provide as an argument for the add command.

Comment: Ok, now I understand (I'm using ver. 0.0.9)